# how to list multiple boxes dimensions in one table? (for wood workers)

Tags: dimensions

if I have kitchen cabinet designed in Blender it consist from multiple boxes with correct dimensions. 
is there a way to list all parts measurements in one table? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm switching from 3Ds Max to Blender so I can design kitchens and make cutlist. So, this is what i have so far and I'm trying to figure out more about Blender and Python so I can have a complete solution for kitchen making.

Try this code, this code export selected objects (kitchen cabinet parts) and store it's name and dimensions into csv file so you can open in excel or send it to cutlist programs like MaxCut.

```
import bpy
#here you need to write where you want to store the file on your system
file = open("/home/monis/Blender/MyFile_02.csv", 'w')
selectedObjects = bpy.context.selected_objects
file.write('Panel name\t hight\t width\t thickness\n')

for obj in selectedObjects:
    dim = obj.dimensions
    file.write(obj.name+'\t'+'{:.3f}\t{:.3f}\t{:.3f}\n'.format(dim.x*100,dim.y*100,dim.z*100))

file.close()
print(obj)
```

[image]

Comment: nice and better answer :) . can you please add a comment to your code (telling users to set correct path on their machines, since windows paths are different ) and I will set it as correct answer

Comment: Thanks Tawfiq abu Halawah for putting an explanation comment in the code, i forgot to do so. 
and thanks Duarte Farrajota Ramos for the approval of the edit

Answer (score 2):

I came up with simple python script to list all selected objects dimensions
it does not validate object type

```
import bpy
selectedObjects = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in selectedObjects:
    partDim = (str(obj.dimensions))
    print(obj.name + partDim)
```

after running the script you can find the list in system console 
you can show the console by going to window-> toggle system console
[image]